# Protocol between parse.com and mobile app

Tags: json, parse-platform

*What is the protocol between parse.com backend and mobile app when using Android/IOS SDK?

For example in the following code how parseobject is returned? Over http as json(Rest), via socket , rpc etc..?

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("GameScore");
query.fromLocalDatastore();
query.getInBackground("xWMyZ4YEGZ", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
  public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
      // object will be your game score
    } else {
      // something went wrong
    }
  }
});
```

*If it is not rest what is the pros of method over REST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does use the Parse REST API, which sends JSON data over HTTPS.

The client SDKs provide a nice, native, helpful experience.  For the platforms we don't support first-party, the REST API is available directly.